# How do I move to the next capital letter?

Tags: vim

In vim I can use `f` followed by a character to go to the next occurrence of that character on the current line. For example, if I have the following (cursor position marked with `|`):

```
m|akeBinExprNode = undefined
```

I can use `fB` to move to `B` and `dtE` to delete until before the `E`, leaving me with:

```
make|ExprNode = undefined
```

I wonder if there's a way to do this that doesn't involve typing the exact character, i.e. some kind of motion that means "go to the next capital letter" and/or "go to right before the next capital letter".

Comment: Are you looking for a solution for camelCase navigation in your code? Because if so then maybe there's room for something fancier than my simple answer...

Comment: You would probably find [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) script interesting.  It works with CamelCase as well as snake_case.

Comment: @wilhelmtell Hmm, yeah, a fancy way to move between camelCase humps would be nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found this [vim tip for moving within CamelCaseWords](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_through_camel_case_words) that might be useful:

```
" Use one of the following to define the camel characters.
" Stop on capital letters.
let g:camelchar = "A-Z"
" Also stop on numbers.
let g:camelchar = "A-Z0-9"
" Include '.' for class member, ',' for separator, ';' end-statement,
" and <[< bracket starts and "'` quotes.
let g:camelchar = "A-Z0-9.,;:{([`'\""
nnoremap <silent><C-Left> :<C-u>call search('\C\<\<Bar>\%(^\<Bar>[^'.g:camelchar.']\@<=\)['.g:camelchar.']\<Bar>['.g:camelchar.']\ze\%([^'.g:camelchar.']\&\>\@!\)\<Bar>\%^','bW')<CR>
nnoremap <silent><C-Right> :<C-u>call search('\C\<\<Bar>\%(^\<Bar>[^'.g:camelchar.']\@<=\)['.g:camelchar.']\<Bar>['.g:camelchar.']\ze\%([^'.g:camelchar.']\&\>\@!\)\<Bar>\%$','W')<CR>
inoremap <silent><C-Left> <C-o>:call search('\C\<\<Bar>\%(^\<Bar>[^'.g:camelchar.']\@<=\)['.g:camelchar.']\<Bar>['.g:camelchar.']\ze\%([^'.g:camelchar.']\&\>\@!\)\<Bar>\%^','bW')<CR>
inoremap <silent><C-Right> <C-o>:call search('\C\<\<Bar>\%(^\<Bar>[^'.g:camelchar.']\@<=\)['.g:camelchar.']\<Bar>['.g:camelchar.']\ze\%([^'.g:camelchar.']\&\>\@!\)\<Bar>\%$','W')<CR>
vnoremap <silent><C-Left> :<C-U>call search('\C\<\<Bar>\%(^\<Bar>[^'.g:camelchar.']\@<=\)['.g:camelchar.']\<Bar>['.g:camelchar.']\ze\%([^'.g:camelchar.']\&\>\@!\)\<Bar>\%^','bW')<CR>v`>o
vnoremap <silent><C-Right> <Esc>`>:<C-U>call search('\C\<\<Bar>\%(^\<Bar>[^'.g:camelchar.']\@<=\)['.g:camelchar.']\<Bar>['.g:camelchar.']\ze\%([^'.g:camelchar.']\&\>\@!\)\<Bar>\%$','W')<CR>v`<o
```

Answer (score 52):

When I searched for that I would be happy to just have the "native" solution: just enter in command mode:

```
/\u
```

which stands for "search for an uppercase letter". After that just move between capital letters with `n` and `N` (shift + n).

Comment: This is awesome! I am recording the sexiest macros that turns camel case into snake case and space-seperated text. No need for plugins or vimrc changes. Unfortunatly it doesn't work with the F-command.

Comment: How can I combine this with the delete command to delete from current cursor position to next uppercase character?

Comment: vim really has a way of making the most simple, obvious solutions to problems make you feel stupid.  @JoyceBabu try `dn`.  I'm using `cn<whatever>` to change some things (which allows you to use `.` to repeat the change)

Comment: @NathanChappell Thank you for the response. But doesn't that require running `/\u` first? Consider the following text `'Aaa|aaaCccc`. If I run, `/\u`, I am already at `C`. So now I need to delete backwards. Did I miss something?

Comment: @JoyceBabu Ah, sorry.  In my case I was thinking that `/\u` was already happening (I was in the middle of a workflow).  You can try a macro like `:nnoremap \dn /\u<cr>``dn`.  This macro fires the `/\u`, then moves back to the old cursor position with (*double backtick*), then does the `dn`.  Is that helpful?

Comment: @JoyceBabu you can also just type `d/\u`. Even if you search for something else with / you will overwrite the search term again when using `.`.
Something very close to your question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8602263/1978365)

Comment: This is the best solution ever, it should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: Hey @Anton Malyshev Can you please share where did you find this? I want to look at all the possible `\x` special usages, it might lead to something useful. Since `\u` is of so much use, we have `\l` which takes us to the next lowercase character, I found it by hit and trial. I wonder if we have more of them to make our life easier.

Comment: Just `:h /` from the vim. It contains the information on the patterns.

Answer (score 16):

I would recommand the following script : [camelcasemotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905). It allows you to jump , delete inner 'camel case words', using <kbd>,</kbd>+ normal navigation [w,b,e] etc...

Comment: This extension works very well. Should mention that you also need to install [VimBall](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1502) to install it.

Answer (score 7):

[wilhelmtell's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958309/how-do-i-move-to-the-next-capital-letter/7958364#7958364) answer will work unless `'ignorecase'` parameter is set. If `'smartcase'` is activated or `'noignorecase'` then it is okay.

However a pattern that can replace `[A-Z]` is `\u` (see `:help /\u` or more globally `:help pattern`). Therefore you can replace your mapping with:

```
:nnoremap <leader>C /\u<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
:nmap <leader>C /[A-Z]<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>
```

Then in normal mode `<leader>C` (which by default means `\C`)

Comment: I believe your solution has a couple of side effects. Like turning off highlighting globally.