# Vim - delete up to searched string

Tags: vim, keyboard, shortcut

Is there a VIM command / key combination that would do something like `dt/mystring` (which doesn't work)?

`dta` tries to find letter `a` on *current line*, but I'd like to delete everything up to searched string (possibly on some other line).

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try this

```
d/mystring
```

It won't delete the string itself.

Comment: This does the job. After the deletion, I have to press :noh to remove the highlighting of search term. Is there a way to delete till search string and not highlight further searches?

Answer (score 24):

`d/mystring` deletes everything up to `mystring`

Edit: aww, too slow :/

Answer (score 24):

Greg Reynolds provided a working solution.
Alternatively if the search pattern is already defined, use:

```
dn
```

the `n` motion is exclusive, so the first character of your pattern won't be eaten.

Another alternative with the [Easymotion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion) plugin you can use `<leader><leader>t<first letter of pattern` (typically leader is backslash) ; then the character just before the pattern will turn into a letter; type this letter and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it without search highlighting and messing your `/` buffer:

```
d:echo search('yourpattern')<CR>
```

For instance, to delete until line starting with 'function':

```
d:echo search('^function')<CR>
```