# How can I use the commands defined in this vim tip?

Tags: vim

I am looking for a way to use `f` followed by some character to jump to the next uppercase letter.

I ran across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958309/how-do-i-move-to-the-next-capital-letter) and want to use the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7958399/391161), since that did not appear to have any dependencies.

However, after I added the lines into my `.vimrc`, I cannot figure out how to actually jump to the next uppercase character.

I tried `Ctrl-Right` and `Ctrl-o`, and both orderings of them, but I could not jump to the next uppercase letter in the line. I also read the actual [vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_through_camel_case_words), but that also does not explain how to actually use the commands.

What is the correct sequence of commands, and in which mode, to actually jump to the next uppercase letter?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be the *f*ind command? What about typing `/[A-Z]`? It'll find the next upper case character (even if it's on a different line), and it's fast to type. Pressing `n` will take you to the next one without retyping the command again.

What you found in the other answer was a macro command. VIM has a rich macro language that allows you to define functions. You can run a function by typing a colon and then its name.

Of course, typing `:findNextCapitalCharacter` is a bit long to type. You can use [map](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)) to define a key macro that will basically type the letters for you to find the next command. I like prefixing my mapped macros with some character like `%`, so typing `%c` will find the next capital character.

---

#### Further Explanation

> I'm currently just doing /\u, but I still want to know how to use the macro in that answer for my own learning. In the case of those macros, what is the actual means to invoke the macro command?

You're way ahead of me! I didn't know about `\u` being uppercase.

Looking at the answer, I see they're not defining a macro, but doing key mapping. Here's a quick intro:

In *command* mode (that's where you can't type in anything into your file, but where you can use commands), type in `:map @$ iHello World` and press return. Now, still in *command* mode, type `@$`. You'll see that VIM typed `iHello World` for you. The `i` put VIM into *insert* mode, so it could type in `Hello World` That's mapping!

In VIM, you have special *map modes* depending on the *mode* you're in. In the original VI, you had two modes: Command and Insert. In VIM, you have Command, Select, Visual, and Command-Pending modes. The different *map* command depend upon the mode. Type `:help mapmode` into VIM and press `<RETURN>` to see about the various map modes and their VIM commands. This will be VIM help manual sections 1.3 to 1.5. Read it thoroughly to understand what the different map command mean.

What the *accepted answer* is doing is entering the maps three different times, once for each mode. There are two different maps (one search to the previous and one search to the next), so six all together.

The *accepted answer* is mapping Cntrl-Left Arrow `<C-left>` and Cntrl-Right Arrow `<C-Right>` to each of these mappings. Much like I mapped `@$` to *Hello World*.

Setting `g:camelcase` is setting a *global* variable called *camelcase* to a string. If the string is `A-Z`, it will be for just capital letters. If it's `A-Z0-9`, it's for capital letters and numbers. You should only define one instance of this variable.

I think you're problem is that you're typing in `<C-Left>` for the map. What you're suppose to type is `^V^->` where `^V` is *Ctrl-V* and `^->` is Ctrl-Left Arrow. When you type that in, the map command will change those into `<C-Left>`.

Comment: I'm currently just doing `/\u`, but I still want to know how to use the macro in that answer for my own learning. In the case of those macros, what is the actual means to invoke the macro command?